# Is it possible to remove 51 degree reference from sitecore 9 installation

Tags: device-detection

We are using sitecore 9.0.2 for one of the project. We do not need device detection in the application and hence device detection is set to false in the config Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.config.
Still after restarting the application i can see error messages related to 51 degree in the log.txt file under app_data. My understanding was that it should not be initializing 51 degree when device detection is not enabled. 
Is there any way I can stop the application to initialize 51 degree dll.
Also, will there be any impact on experience editor if i disable device detection?

```
   2019-03-26T01:39:21.3062387Z - 12072 - Info - Creating data set from 'FiftyOne.Foundation' version '3.2.17.2'
2019-03-26T01:39:21.3302389Z - 12072 - Info - Exception getting data file date from file 'c:\sitecore\cm\website\App_Data\51Degrees.mobi-Premium-2015.04.07.dat'
2019-03-26T01:39:21.3432434Z - 12072 - Info - Created temp data file - "c:\sitecore\cm\website\App_Data\51Degrees\51Degrees.mobi-Premium-2015.04.07.dat.68c17046-6ba3-4c5b-b716-8d6f687fc7a2.tmp"
2019-03-26T01:39:21.3892349Z - 12072 - Fatal - Exception processing device data from binary file 'c:\sitecore\cm\website\App_Data\51Degrees.mobi-Premium-2015.04.07.dat'. Enable debug level logging and try again to help identify cause.
2019-03-26T01:39:21.3892349Z - 12072 - Fatal - 
2019-03-26T01:39:21.3892349Z - 12072 - Fatal - Data file is invalid. Check that the data file is decompressed and is version '3.1.0.0,3.2.0.0' format.
```

Comment: I know the error i because of invalid license file, but i do not need the license

Comment: If you have disabled it with this patch : `<setting name="DeviceDetection.Enabled" value="false" />`, then I would contact Sitecore Support to give you fix for this. Seems like a bug.